# Windows python 3.5 Tensorflow cuda file loading

Tags: windows, tensorflow, python-3.5

Here is my error message first i get when trying to import tensorflow:

> > > import tensorflow

```
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:119] Couldn't open CUDA library cublas64_80.dll
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_blas.cc:2294] Unable to load cuBLAS DSO.
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:119] Couldn't open CUDA library cudnn64_5.dll
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:3459] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:119] Couldn't open CUDA library cufft64_80.dll
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_fft.cc:344] Unable to load cuFFT DSO.
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library nvcuda.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:119] Couldn't open CUDA library curand64_80.dll
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_rng.cc:338] Unable to load cuRAND DSO.
```

here is what i have installed:

windows 10 pro, python 3.5, then installed
 Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 ( as suggested on tensorflow page)
then i installed tensorflow via pip (the gpu version, and it installed sucessfully)
Cuda 8.0
Cudnn 5.1 ( copied the files into my cuda folder)
my Path variable looks like this :

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\libnvvp
C:\Program Files\Python35\Scripts\
C:\Program Files\Python35\
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0
```

I really am clueless where i went wrong :(

Comment: In which directory is the `cublas64_80.dll` file located?  Use the windows file find function if you're not sure.  Once you've identified the directory that contains that, try adding it to your path variable.  Repeat the process for `cudnn64_5.dll`

Comment: I should have just restarted, that was the issue i think .. but thank you for your help Robert !